# iphone/ios - core data relationship concept

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, core-data, relationship

I have a concept problem and I hope you guys can help me! On my app the user and his contacts can create events and share it.

here is my app model:

[app model http://img407.imageshack.us/img407/7900/bildschirmfoto20130423ur.png](http://img407.imageshack.us/img407/7900/bildschirmfoto20130423ur.png)

On App start I create my Profile (User) and fill the contact entity. Now I, or my contacts, can create an Event. For an Event I can select participants.

My Question is now: when I add Participants I have to **add** them also to the contact list right? So they will be **twice** in it.

In a relational database I would do a table that connect those two entities and shows the participants.

How can I implement that in core data? any advice to improve my model would be great! thank you!

Comment: Just for clarity in your app you have a user, user has friends. A user can create an event and can invite friends. Is that correct?

Comment: @Anupdas yes exactly and friends (contacts) can also creates events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Have an id everywhere it is possible. It will be very helpful. If you have contact id then add the contact id to participants and you can have more info related to participation (like you mentioned accepted or not.. etc,.)

Comment: but for what is the relationship than for? Can i use the NSManagedObjectID that returns when I insert the contacts for it? ty for your fast reply

Comment: what is the diff b/w user and contact?

Comment: a user is always the actual app user.. the user has contacts.. the problem is that a contact can also creates multiple events and invite me to that event.. sorry for my slow thinking...

Comment: in your example i dont need a id anymore right? or i m wrong?

Comment: then take every one as a user and relate users with events.

Comment: I usually give id for every entity whether it is useful for now or not, because we should have some primary key to identify each recored.

Comment: sry that i ask you again.. is there a way to realise a primary key?